# he-IL Hebrew locale incorrect date format Angular 4

Tags: angular, date-pipe

Using angular 4 date pipe to format dates. For he-IL (Hebrew) locale I see the data format as dd.mm.yyyy instead of dd/mm/yyyy

Not sure why this discrepancy?

Comment: What's your question? You can use a date pipe to define your own formatting, per the documentation. If you think the default internationalization is wrong you are free to open a ticket with the Angular team.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `toLocaleDateString()` in your case:

```js
var date = new Date().toLocaleDateString('he-IL');
console.log(date);
date = date.replace(/\./g, '/');
console.log(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your pipe:

```js
| date:'d/M/yy':'UTC+6'
```